# Non-existing removable disks

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive

win xp sp3

I have four non-existing removable disks

Removable Disk (D:)
Removable Disk (E:)
Removable Disk (F:)
Removable Disk (G:)

I tried everything to remove them. Even formatting entire hard disk and re-installing OS. Without result.

Any help !

I don't have any card reader or extra device attached to the comp, except keyboard, mouse and monitor.

Comment: Do you have a build in multi-card reader?  (Think of a device for reading CDcards, CF cards etc etc).

Comment: What devices do you have attatched to your computer.  Update your question.

Comment: @Hennes, I updated the post, please check

Comment: @Ramhound, I updated the post, please check

Comment: what model is your computer?

Comment: @EBGreen, it's `HP Compaq`, mainboard is `0A64h` chipset - `ATI Xpress 200 (RS480)`.

Comment: What model Compaq?

Comment: You have more then just a keyboard, mouse, and monitor connected to your computer I guarantee you that.

Comment: If you check the properties of these drives, what are the details listed?

Answer (score 1):

This is typical behavior of a card-reader. Even while your edit says you do not have a card-reader, attaching a USB drive that has 4 partitions or a build-in card reader will show these. Like a printer with a card-reader hidden somewhere in the control interface.

The best way to find this card-reader, is to unplug all USB drives, reboot the computer, and plugin all cables one by one, wait for the device to install and then check if it added the 4 drives. I bet you'll get them when you install your printer with build-in card reader. ;)

Comment: LPChip, I have no any printer. Removable drives appears on starting windows, without any devices attached, except mouse and keyboard.

Comment: Just to make 100% sure: No USB cable to the monitor? (Typed from behind a Dell 2407 WFP-HC with SM/SD/MMC/CFcard reader)

Comment: @bonaca - does you computer have a **built-in** card reader? Even though these are built-in, they typically are internally connected to the motherboard through USB.